# how to attach information in key "documentData" - docusign

Tags: php, docusignapi, clickwrap

I need help, at the moment of signing a clickWrap template, in the platform where the code fragment of the respective template was embedded, I don't have the "documentData" key, where in the sandbox account it is available, while in the production account it is not.

production account:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYTv7.png)

demo account:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTC4Z.png)

As you can see in the images, in the test account, we have the key "DocumentData", while in the production account, we do not!

Someone knows how to activate this option, since I send this information in production, but I get the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeVry.png)

I look forward to hearing from you!

I tried activating and deactivating various settings in the account, but no luck!

Comment: Please do not use external pictures, as links can become inactive over time. Insert your code as text, to increase the probability of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please contact customer support for DocuSign, we need to know your account number so we can change a settings in your account to enable dynamic content.

Comment: ok, generate a case in the portal  https://support.docusign.com/s/contactSupport?language=en_US.
Number: 10732074